# Maximum size of a virtual pool in SCVMM 2012R2

Tags: storage, windows-server-2012-r2, scvmm

I have a *Windows Server 2012 R2* running *SCVMM 2012 R2* and an over-committed virtual storage pool. In *Server Manager* the capacity of this storage pool is **128TB** which translates to **140TiB** which makes sense since the maximum allowed size by the storage array is **140TiB**. This same storage pool is shown under *VMM* with the size of **131,072GB** (**131TB**) which is **144TiB**.

Where is this size coming from? Is this the maximum size allowed by the *SCVMM*? Or does *SCVMM* use different measurement units?